# When converting a string to double the output is whitout leading zeros

Tags: c#, type-conversion, format, double

I have a textbox where i get my string value from.
When using

```
tbValue = (Convert.ToDouble(tbValue.text) * -1.0).toString();
```

the output is allways without the leading zeros.

when the value is 0,8 it returns -8 in the textbox.

Is there a way to keep the leading zero when using Convert.ToDouble?

Comment: There is no leading zero in "0,8"

Comment: what's your locale? by any chance, is it one with a `.` as decimal separator?

Comment: Do not trust user input. `Convert.ToDouble` will _crash_ your app if you enter bs.

Comment: A number has no leading zeroes. A string representing one does, but a double (variable type) has no unneeded leading zeroes.

Comment: That said, if "0,8" turns into 8, then this is a parsing error in your locale (used in ToDouble) not recognizing the "," as the decimal separator. Try "0.8" and se whether this is parsed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your error is not about "leading zeroes". A double is a value, values have no surplus leading zeroes (like in 003.3) - those are added in formatting the output.

If your input of "0.8" is recognized as "8" that is not a leading zero issue, it is a decimal separator issue - the "ToDouble" part is assuming - likely - that there is a "." as decimal separator, so the "," is ignored. The number is only a proper number if parsed with the correct locale for your system (default is to the system language). You can give an explicit locale in Parsing, check all overloads of ToDouble.

Comment: And taking the input from something called `tbValue.text` I'd also recommend using something like [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: The "," replaces the "." as decimal separator in the German language so it is "18,3" not "18.3".

Comment: I checked the documentation of double.TryParse and found a solution. Thanks for the reminder to check up on "how to handle data types properly".

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "," ?
It works with "."

```
    string input = "0.8";
    string tbValue = (Convert.ToDouble(input) * -1.0).ToString();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XAsNhe

Answer (score 1):

This work

```
string tbValue = (Convert.ToDouble(tbValue.Text.Replace(",","."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * -1.0).ToString();
```